# How can I destroy the session after the user go to another page?

Tags: php

How can I destroy the session after the user  go to another page !?

I make a search form that give the user1 name, after this I open a session, it give me data
the problem is when I search for another user in the same page, the data that the user2 not have, it take it from user1
I want to delete the last session when I start a new search !? or when I got to another page !?

Comment: you can use `unset($_SESSION['yoursessionvariable'])` for single variable or use this `session_destroy()` to destroy all session variable.

Answer (score 0):

There's possibility to use `session_destroy()` function in PHP, but this **is not** generally recommended, because calling `session_destroy()` destroys all the session data and not only those you want to be destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to destroy the session on each page load, and start it over you need to destroy the session and then start it again. See [session_destroy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php), this code snippet is taken from the PHP documentation. You can use register_shutdown_function to call this last

```
register_shutdown_function(function() {
  if(session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
  }
  $_SESSION = array();
  if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
   setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
     $params["path"], $params["domain"],
     $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
  }
  session_destroy();
});
```

Comment: Put it at the top of your file. It is still a little unclear on what you are trying to do.

Comment: i got blank page ,, white page !? ,,

Comment: i try it but not work ,, what i need is after the page loading ,, destroy the session

Comment: see edit, you can use register_shutdown_function to destroy it